# AWS S3/CloudFront Ignores Content-Disposition/Type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

So I have some .png files stored onto an S3 bucket that is set as the origin of my Cloudfront Disribution. In the metadata of the .png files, I have manually set the content-type and the content-disposition (though I found that 'inline' wasn't one of the default available values for content-disposition). However, even though the Object URL in S3 displays the image inline, the Cloudfront url immediately downloads the file. Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Do you see if headers returns in response are same for Cloudfront and S3 ? May be cloudfront is still serving from cache ?

Comment: @JamesDean That actually might be it, but I have no clue how to check that. So uhh any tips? lol